# How to get cross-domain JSON from jQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest, jsonp

I am trying to get JSON (getJSON()) from server that doesn't have support for jsonp implemented. Namely, when adding `callback=?` to the URL, the server does return the data, but it returns pure JSON without padding.

I understand this is something that must be corrected server-side - there is no way to resolve it in jQuery. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. If the server does not support JSONP you can not get any data from it via regular AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

If CORS support is not supported by server as well `jsonp`, you might try proxy approach in such cases. One example http://www.corsproxy.com/, there should be other proxy alternatives too.

**What does it do?**

CORS Proxy allows javascript code on your site to access resources on other domains that would normally be blocked due to the same-origin policy.

**How does it work?**

CORS Proxy takes advantage of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, which is a feature that was added along with HTML 5. Servers can specify that they want browsers to allow other websites to request resources they host. CORS Proxy is simply an HTTP Proxy that adds a header to responses saying "anyone can request this".